# Checking whether files exists against an array in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I'm new to this site and apologies if this has been answered before but although I can find parts of the answer to my question on this site I cannot find a solution to what I'm trying to do.

What I need to do is, within a batch script, define a list of files and then loop through a directory containing some data files and ensure that the files that have been delivered to that directory match what's in my list. If they don't then build a string which is carriage return delimited which will then form the text for an email alert that will get called at the end of the batch. What I have thus far is this:

```
echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET ImportDirectory=D:\Data Files\

SET MissingFiles=

@REM Build Array of sorts

@set  arrayline[0]=%ImportDirectory%File1*.xml

@set  arrayline[1]=%ImportDirectory%File2*.xml

@set  arrayline[2]=%ImportDirectory%File3*.xml etc

@REM Loop through and check whether file exists
@for /l %%n in (0,1,2) do (

if not exist !arrayline[%%n]! (
    echo File does not exist
    SET MissingFiles=%MissingFiles%!arrayline[%%n]!

    REM echo File !arrayline[%%n]! has not been delivered for processing >> %LogFilePath%
    echo File !arrayline[%%n]! has not been delivered for processing
) else (
echo File Exists
)
)

@REM Test to see if any files are missing and send email
IF NOT %MissingFiles% == "" (
@REM Call code that sends the email with Missing Files as the body
)
```

When I try and to run this it runs but my error list doesn't get built. I can echo out the !arrayline[%%n]! variable each time in the loop but it doesn't write or append to the Missing File variable. Similarly if I try to output the results to a file nothing get outputted - I just get various messages about echo being off.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using delayed expansion for `!arrayline[%%n]!` but nor for `%MissingFiles%`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET ImportDirectory=D:\Data Files\
SET MissingFiles=
REM Build Array of sorts
set "arrayline[0]=%ImportDirectory%File1*.xml"
set "arrayline[1]=%ImportDirectory%File2*.xml"
set "arrayline[2]=%ImportDirectory%File3*.xml"

REM Loop through and check whether file exists
for /l %%n in (0,1,2) do (
    if not exist !arrayline[%%n]! (
        echo File does not exist
        SET "MissingFiles=!MissingFiles!,!arrayline[%%n]!"

        REM echo File !arrayline[%%n]! has not been delivered for processing >> %LogFilePath%
        echo File !arrayline[%%n]! has not been delivered for processing
    ) else (
      echo File !arrayline[%%n]! Exists
    )
)

REM Test to see if any files are missing and send email
IF NOT "%MissingFiles%" == "" (
    Echo Missingfiles:  %MissingFiles:~1%
    REM Call code that sends the email with Missing Files as the body
)
```